# Raising Additional Events in BackgroundWorker's DoWork Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, user-interface, backgroundworker

I am trying to run a long running instance method on another thread from my UI, but still report progress back to the GUI thread to update a progress bar.  I know there are a lot of ways to do this and many questions on SO regarding this.  The long running instance method I have actually has two events of it's own.  It has an event that fires on PropertyChanged, which is for reporting of the current work completed & current total work that needs to be completed.  It also has an OperationCompleted event.  I was planning on using a `BackgroundWorker` in my UI to run this long-running method on a separate thread.  What I am trying to figure out is the following:

If I create event handlers for the PropertyChanged & OperationCompleted events, can I implement them to raise `BackgroundWorker` events?  Will this allow them all run on the background thread and essentially simulate an event bubbling to the UI thread?  Below is an example:

```
class GUI : Form
{
     private BackgroundWorker back = new BackgroundWorker();
     back.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
     back.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(myWork);
     back.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(myWork_changed);
     back.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(myWork_completed);

     /* GUI CODE OMITTED */

     private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          back.RunWorkerAsync();
     }
     private void myWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
          Syncer sync = new Syncer();
          sync.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(sync_PropertyChanged);
          sync.OperationCompleted += new EventHandler(sync_OperationCompleted);
          sync.LongRunningMethod();

     }
     private void sync_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
           //calculations & logic as needed
           back.ReportProgress(calculated);
     }
     //might not be necessary to implement because of how BackgroundWorker functions
     private void sync_OperationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           back.ReportProgress(100);
     }

     private void myWork_changed(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
     {
          //update UI progress bar
     }
     private void myWork_completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
          //tasks needed @ completion such as hide progress bar
     }
```

So will the events of the Syncer class fire on the same thread as the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork()` method?  Is this thread safe?  Criticism & alternative suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Syncer() class events will fire from whatever thread is actually raising them.  That might be the same thread as the DoWork() handler, it might not be.  We don't know the internal workings of the Syncer() class, so we can't tell from the code you've posted.

It's fine, however, to call ReportProgress() from the Syncer() events.  Regardless of what thread they fire on, this will still result in the ProgressChanged() and RunWorkerCompleted() events being raised in the main UI thread (assuming the BackgroundWorker() was created by the main UI thread itself; which it was in this case).

You don't need to manually Invoke() anything, that's the whole point of using the BackgroundWorker() in the first place...to avoid the need to do that.

If you didn't use the BackgroundWorker() and "bubble" the events via its built-in events, and instead wrapped the Syncer() operation in a **manual** thread, then yes, you'd need to manually Invoke() updates to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Events raised from the background worker thread will run on and block that thread and can in turn raise ReportProgress events which will also run on and block the worker thread so long as it can access a reference to the BackgroundWorker.

If you bear this in mind and use invoke calls to update the UI it should work fine.

Comment: The `ReportProgress` event is still on the GUI thread though, correct?

Comment: No, all event handlers run on the thread that raises the event. You need to use GUI.Invoke() to run code on the main gui thread.